# Predator–Prey Equation and Liapunov's Stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

**Problem :**

> Given the non-linear system:
>   $$ x'=(a-b\cdot y)\cdot x $$
>   $$y'=(-c+d\cdot x)\cdot y $$
>   $$ a,b,c,d>0$$ also known as *the predator–prey equation*.
>
> Also, **Lyapunov's function** $$V=(y^a\cdot e^{-b\cdot y})\cdot (x^c\cdot e^{-d\cdot y})$$ is given
>
> - Prove that the non-linear system is stable to the stationary point $$A\bigg(\dfrac{c}{d},\dfrac{a}{b}\bigg)$$

Firstly,
I solved the system take four different cases:

For $$x=0$$ $$y=0$$ i take the stationary point $$O(0,0)$$

For $$x\neq 0$$   $$y=0$$ which is not possible

For $$x=0$$ $$y\neq 0$$ which is not possible

and finally.
For $$x\neq 0$$ $$y\neq 0$$
we take the given stationary point $$A(\dfrac{c}{d},\dfrac{a}{b})$$

I differentiate the liapunov's function and i take:
$$V'=(y^a\cdot e^{-b\cdot y}\cdot c\cdot x^{-d\cdot x}-d\cdot y^a\cdot e^{-b\cdot y}\cdot x^c\cdot e^{-d\cdot x})\cdot x' + (a\cdot y^{a-1}\cdot e^{-b\cdot y}\cdot x^c \cdot e^{-d\cdot x}-b\cdot y^a\cdot e^{-b\cdot y}\cdot x^c\cdot e^{-d\cdot x})\cdot y'$$

Ι have to find that $$V'\leq 0$$ so to prove that A is a **stable point** but i have some difficulties to prove this.Can anyone help with this?

I would really appreciate a thorough solution and explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to differentiate $V(x, y)$ w.r.t. time. What I see in your $V'$ reminds more $V'_x(x, y) + V'_y(x, y)$ than $V'_x (x, y)\cdot \dot{x} + V'_y(x, y)\cdot \dot{y}$. So you have to differentiate that correctly and gather all terms in the resulted expression.

Comment: oh my mistake you have right!I forgοt to add x' and y'.

Comment: I think $e^{-d\cdot y}$ should be $e^{-d\cdot x}$.

Comment: Yeah, but you still haven't substituted $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ into the expression for $V'$. Do it, then gather terms and simplify the expression.

Comment: maybe, i'll check it!

Answer (score 1):

By differentiating the two components of $V$ separately, you can see that $g(y) = y^a\cdot e^{-b\cdot y}$ has a global maximum at $y = \frac{a}{b}$ and that $h(x)=x^c\cdot e^{-d\cdot x}$ has a global maximum at $x = \frac{c}{d}$. Thus $V$ has a global maximum at $\left(\frac{c}{d},\,\frac{a}{b}\right)$.